# Is there a way to minimize my boolean modifiers?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a long corridor that I'm putting a bunch of windows in and, I have a cube put in where I want the windows with a simple boolean modifier setup to the object I'm wanting to penetrate  and it's working perfectly except I want to add a heap of windows to the wall and I don't want to have to add a billion boolean modifiers to the wall. Is there a way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Can't you use the Array modifier on the object used to create the hole in the window?

Comment: Yes sorry, I tried it before but apparently I didn't separate the two cubes enough lol

Answer (score 1):

Use the Array modifier on the window cube. Make sure to increase the relative distance to be greater than 1.0 otherwise, your cubes won't separate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only need one boolean modifier if you are using the same object for all the windows, so you can go to edit mode of the cutting object and just duplicate the windows and move them around as a mesh of a single object from edit mode.